# Colimits of symmetric groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

The infinite symmetric group $S_{\infty}$ of finitely supported permutations of $\mathbb{N}$ can be written as a colimit over the $S_n$'s with respect to the embedding $S_{n} \to S_{n+1}$ that maps $\sigma \in S_n$ to the elements of $S_{n+1}$ that fixes $n+1$ and permutes $\{1,\dots, n\}$ according to $\sigma$.

However, if we fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is another natural colimit one can consider: Let $\varphi_k$ be the group homomorphism
$$
\varphi_k \colon S_{n^k} \to S_{n^{k+1}}
$$
that maps $\sigma \in S_{n^k}$ to the block permutation $(\sigma, \dots, \sigma)$ of the set with $n^{k+1}$ elements.

> Q1: Does the colimit with respect to these maps have a name under which it has been studied before?

The classifying space of the groupoid $G$ of finite sets and bijective maps is
$$
BG \simeq \coprod_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0} BS_n
$$
and the disjoint union of sets induces a monoidal structure with respect to which we can take the group completion $\Omega B (BG)$, which is homotopy equivalent to $\Omega^\infty S^\infty$ by the Barratt-Priddy theorem.

> Q2: How is the above colimit from Q1 related to the groupoid of finite sets with cardinality $n^k$ for some $k$ and monoidal structure given by the cartesian product?

Comment: If I am not mistaken the colimit in the case when $n$ is a prime number has been studied, but unfortunately I can't recall where I saw it.

Comment: Please could you add something to explain the algebraic topology tag?

Comment: @MarkWildon  done

Comment: I found the reference, it is in McDuff - Segal Homology fibrations and the "group completion" theorem, Example iv).

Comment: One tiny observation: when $n=2$ the image of each inclusion map is a group of even permutations, so using $\mathrm{Hom}(\varinjlim S_{n^k}, \{+1,-1\}) \cong \varprojlim \mathrm{Hom}(S_{n^k}, \{+1,-1\})$, the only homomorphism from the colimit to $\{+1,-1\}$ is the trivial map. This distinguishes the colimit from the group of finitary permutations of an infinite set.

Comment: @user43326 Ohh! Thank you! That is a very helpful reference that answers Q2 for prime n as well,

Comment: Here is a link to the McDuff and Segal reference: https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/mcduff-segal.pdf

Comment: @MarkWildon Great. Thank you!